# How to add the result of a query to another field by some critiria access

Tags: sql, ms-access

The description of the tables are as follow:

```
Moves: IDPro, IDMove, Quantity, Date
Stock: IDPRo, Quantity, IDstock
Products: IDPro, Quantity, Name, Price
```

Its a basic inventory access database where every product has a number of movement either positive or negative so the sum of that should be the stock quantity of the specific product. I Want to sum all the moves of each individual item and then update each individual stock quantity field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you want make an update. Because every time a new move appear you will need another update. That sound more like a trigger, and I belive access doesn't allow that.

You are better creating a **[VIEW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836312.aspx)** and access a `view_Stock` instead of the real table

Something Like this:

```
CREATE VIEW view_Stock (IDPRo, IDstock, Quantity) AS 
  SELECT S.IDPro, S.IDstock, SUM (M.Quantity)
  FROM Stock S
  INNER JOIN Moves M
          ON S.IDPRo = M.IDPRo
  GROUP BY S.IDPro, S.IDstock
```

Comment: Its a great idea, but do you know how could be the code for that VIEW?

Comment: well that is another question, But check my edit, just not 100 % sure and dont have `access` to test it.

Comment: Thanks so much!, thats exctly what i was looking for, the only thing that i need to add i the "group by" because it demands me to put it because of the use of "sum". But thanks

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that. Remember accept/upvote if this answer your question.

Comment: i'm new to this. Thanks again. I give an upvote but i can't by now haha